# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Timeout exceeded getting exception details Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

After following a tutorial when i try to run my code i get `Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Timeout exceeded getting exception details` on app start.I tried `clean` and `Rebuild` but it doesn't fix it. When i try to debug i noticed that its on the `onCreate` method but i am not understanding the reason its throwing  exception since the code has not error on build.
Below is the code in the `base.onCreate` method

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.LocationService);
        provider = locationManager.GetBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
        Location location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No Location");
        }
    }
```

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" 
  package="XamarinWeatherApp.XamarinWeatherApp" 
  android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
   />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission 
  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" 
  />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
  android:label="@string/app_name" 
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" 
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It is hard to see where the problem is only by viewing the information you posted. I suggest you post a demo so that we can test it for you.

Comment: what information should i post?

Comment: A demo is best, if you would like to.

Answer (score 0):

Check manifest.xml,make sure Activity add properly and check permission for location.

Comment: I have added the Manifest, please check it.

Comment: R u added in this manner? [Activity(Label = "labelName", Icon = "@drawable/image", LaunchMode =LaunchMode.SingleTask, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]